# IIS Update reset browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I wanted to know if there is a way to reset browser cache once I update web server with new code? I have JavaScript that is I want to make sure they user has the most update version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS you can change the Content Expiry Header to force the client to get the latest versions of the files.

1. Open IIS Manager, select your site.
2. From the middle pane double click on the **HTTP Response Headers**.

[image]

3)On the HTTP Response Headers page, in the Actions pane, click Set Common Headers.

4)In the Set Common HTTP Response Headers dialog box, select the Expire Web content checkbox and select one of the following options:

- Select **Immediately** if you want the content to expire immediately after it is sent in a response.
- Select **After** if you want the content to expire periodically. Then, in the corresponding boxes, type an integer and select a time interval at which content expires. For example, type 1 and select Days if you want the content to expire daily.
- Select **On** (in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)) if you want the content to expire on a specific day and at a specific time. Then, in the corresponding boxes, select a date and time at which the content expires.

[image]

If you have access to the source code all modern browsers will treat resources such as a CSS, Javascript as new versions if you append a query string to them which is unique.

E.g

http://example.com/test.js?v=1.1

The actual content of the query string doesn’t matter as long as it’s unique, however, most developers will tend to use v for version and then just set it to be the build number.